# Python while loop not working perfectly as expected

Tags: python, while-loop

```
choice = " "
while choice not 'Y' or choice not 'N' :
    choice = input("Y for Yes or N for No")
```

What is the mistake i have made in this while loop?

Comment: Hi ! You did not mentionned what do you expect from your code :-) Do you have also an error message or an answer given that you do not expect here ?

Comment: no error but condition is not working perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 choice = " "
 while not (choice  == 'Y' or choice ==  'N') :
      choice = input("Y for Yes or N for No")
```

Please Try with this code

Answer (score 2):

this might help (python3.x is confusing, when comes to syntax):

```
 choice = " "
 while choice != 'Y' or choice != 'N' :
      choice = input("Y for Yes or N for No")
```

Answer (score 1):

"not" is different than "not equal to". Use this instead,

```
choice = " "
while choice!='Y' or choice!='N':
    choice = input("Y for Yes or N for No")
```